# Проблема с записью данных в txt-файл

Tags: python-3.x, discord-api

***ПРОГРАММА***

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    my_file = open("{0}.txt".format(message.author.id), "w")
    myfile1 = open("{0}.txt".format(message.author.id), "r")
    myfile1.read()
    my_file.write(myfile1.read() ++ number)
    my_file.close()
```

***ОШИБКА***

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\senuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "overmind.py", line 821, in on_message
    my_file.write(myfile1.read() ++ number)
```

number = 1 
Я пытаюсь считывать кол-во сообщений, что бы потом выводить их в статистику о пользователе, но не понимаю в чем ошибка и как ее исправить, может кто-нибудь знает?

Comment: у вас многочисленные ошибки в крошечном фрагменте коде. Попробуйте более простые задачи сперва (по одной за раз): "как число в строку превратить", "как записать число в файл", "как изменить файл по месту", "как добавить к числу записанному в файле"¶ Если не ясно как какую-то задачу решать, то создайте минимальный пример кода, который показывает где вы застряли и опубликуйте его как отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос (для задач, которые я перечислил, если код упоминает discord, то ваш пример не минимальный).

Answer (score 0):

Я не особо как-то вник в тою проблему ну да ладно... Что значит `my_file.write(myfile1.read() ++ number)` ? Если ты хочешь сложить число и с файла с другим числом то как минимум должно быть `my_file.write(int(myfile1.read()) + number)` ? Я могу ошибаться, но по мне, как-то так должно работать...